# How to compute Cumulative values in Shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I would like to compute cumulative values from the below data file and writing them into columns after inserting a serial number.

```
ifile.txt
1 2 3 2 3 1 4 5 1 
3 4 5 2 3 4 1 3 1 
1 3 2 3 2 4 1 2 4 ...............
```

Where ifile.txt has 3 rows and 9 columns in this example.
Desire output:

```
ofile.txt
1  1   3   1
2  3   7   4
3  6   12  6
4  8   14  9
5  11  17  11
6  12  21  15
7  16  22  16
8  21  25  18
9  22  26  22
.  
.  
.
```

Here first column is used for the serial number.
So what I did is: I first converted into columns using

```
awk '{ 
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
    a[NR,i] = $i
     }
}
NF>p { p = NF }
END {    
for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
    str=a[1,j]
    for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
        str=str" "a[i,j];
    }
    print str
    }
 }' ifile.txt > ifile1.txt
```

Then I use awk

```
awk '{print m1=$1+m1, m2=$2+m2, m3=$3+m3}' ifile1.txt > ofile.txt
```

I can't proceed for the next step i.e. to insert a column of serial number. Also I can't make it for arbitrary columns and rows.

Comment: what is formula for col3 and col4 in ofile.txt?

Comment: @Kayan: Do you guarantee that it's a matrix? i.e. every single row contains the same count of numbers.

Comment: The formula seems to be: 1. first do a transpose of the input matrix (i.e. 90 degree rotate, or row-column exchange).  2. accumulate number in the same column, for total 3 columns in the example.  @ShravanYadav: since it only has 3 rows in the input, the output should only contains 3 columns, plus the header serial number column.

Comment: Yes, you are right @RobinHsu. I have modified the transpose script to get 90 degree rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for column of serial number

```
awk '{print i=i+1,m1=$1+m1, m2=$2+m2, m3=$3+m3}' ifile1.txt > ofile.txt
```

and for complete solution of your logic

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(i>1)$i=$i+$(i-1);f[i]=f[i]" "$i}if(NF>n)n=NF}END{for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print i,f[i]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lane '
           $l = 0;
           push @s, [ map { $l = $l + $F[$_] } 0 .. $#F];
           }{
           for $i (0 .. $#{$s[0]}) {
               print join " ", $i + 1, map $s[$_][$i], 0 .. $#s;
           }' < ifile.txt > ofile.txt
```

- `-l` adds newlines to `print`
- `-a` splits each line into the `@F` array
- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `$l` is the "last sum" for each row
- `@s` is the array of arrays that keeps the sums

Answer (score 1):

A better way to produce serial numbers in the header:

First, forget the serial numbers, just focus on the generation of the results.  Say you manage to get a temporal results in `tmp_ofile.txt`, without serial numbers.

Then, just do

```
cat -n tmp_ofile.txt > ofile.txt
```

You will get the serial number header.